# Possible Bug Inside Line + Graphics + PlotRange, Why and How to Fix It?

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs

**I work on Mathematica 11.0.0**

I'm working on a ray tracing program and I need to visualize lightrays and their intersections. Everything works fine until today I tried to visualize two nearly parallel lightrays and their faraway intersecting point, this time, the Front-End simple crashed and stop responding. I found the problems lies in `Graphics` when rendering a long `Line` or `Arrow` with `PlotRange` setting.

---

Try this piece of code

```
Table[Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {10^x, 0}}]}], {x, .5, 8, .5}]
Table[Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {10^x, 0}}]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {x, .5, 8, .5}]
```

The first piece of code generate quite reasonable result, but the second seemingly don't:
In the first few pictures, everything works fine, but in latter ones, the line shifted to the left side instead of right side, then when x keeps going larger, the whole line vanished:

[image: error image]

I found out the "magical limit of reversing" is *125334*

and the "magical limit of disappearing" is *16049956* and things goes nasty near this place:

[image: nasty]

To my surprise, these are not power of 2, so I don't know what's going on here.

A easy way to fix it is adding a replacement rule to set those "overflowing" values to a reasonable one using `graphics/.n_?NumericQ:>Clip[n,{-10000,10000}]`, but that's really low in efficiency and will tamper the data which is extremly unwanted if I want to extract some data from this image later on.

---

Well, while the first phenomenon is still bearable, the second surely is not!

**Please save all your work before running this piece of code:**

```
Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {1.*^6, 0}}]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

Front-End keeps running! I suspect this happen because Mathematica draw all dashed line segments first and then show us the portion in `PlotRange`. Those excessing line segments drawing crashes the Front-End.

---

So my problem is, why these happen and how can I solve it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like a bug, I'd report it to WRI

Comment: @user6014 I shall report it too.

Comment: I get the same with versions 8.0.4, 10.4.1 and 11.0.0 on Win7 x64. It is a bug.

Comment: Upgrade to 11.0.1. I don't see those problems with 11.0.1 on macOS. Now, the last bit of code still gives the FE fits, but not enough to crash, just a bit of unresponsiveness.

Comment: @rcollyer well, but the decrease in performance is **disastrous** when I draw thousands of these lines in my real application. But maybe I should upgrade my Mathematica to check whether it could solve the problem :)

Comment: @Wjx the issue is the monstrously large numbers. Maybe there's another way to get at the info you need?